# Do all 10-speed chains fit 3x10?

Tags: road-bike, chain, derailleur, gears

I'm wondering if all 10-speed chains fit to 3x10. A lot of webshops say that the chain is "for road bikes 2x10" or something like that. Or nothing at all.
The chain I have right now (Shinano CN HG-54) is "ultra narrow", but I'm not sure if that's because it's a 10-speed, or if there are sizing issues between 1x10, 2x10, and 3x10.

I appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 speed works with 10 speed. You will be fine with the chain you have. The major difference being that the one that is made for 3x10 will be a couple links longer generally. Usually this is designated by a number such as 116L where the L stands for links.

Width wise you should be fine with any 10 speed chain. 10sp chains are slightly more narrow than a 9sp so that they could pack that extra cog on the cassette. Although when you look at the difference it is minuscule.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and feel a bit more safe buying one then.